# Determine if DFAs accept any word which contains bb

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata, decision-problem

Let $\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$. Describe an algorithm that takes as input a deterministic finite
automaton $M= (Q,\Sigma,\tau,s,A)$ and determines whether or not $M$ accepts a word containing $bb$ (i.e., a word of the form $\alpha bb \gamma$ for some $\alpha,\gamma \in\Sigma^*$). You do not have to give a formal proof that your algorithm is correct but you should indicate why this is the case.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Just dumping your exercise problem here does not help you learning.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: @RickDecker Editing questions that are on hold causes them to be automatically nominated for re-opening. There's not much point editing an old, negatively voted, on-hold question if all you're going to do is change the typesetting.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

- The language $BBS$ consisting of all strings over $\{a, b, c\}$ with a substring $bb$ is regular. (Consider the language denoted by the regular expression $(a\cup b\cup c)^*bb(a\cup b\cup c)^*$).
- The intersection of two regular languages is regular.
- There is a standard decision algorithm to determine whether a regular language is empty.

So if the language of your input FA, $M$ is $L$, what does $L\cap BBS$ tell you about whether $M$ accepts a string "$\dotsm bb \dotsm$"?